# How do I find an element with a specific class and CSS style using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what the code looks like:

```
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' style="display:block;">
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the `div` with `class5` and CSS property `display` set to `block`. Once I have this `div` I want to perform further action on that `div`. I tried using something like

```
$('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4').find( '.class5').is(':visible')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please indent code when pasting it into a question; it makes it far easier to read that way.

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/fqqbqyb8/1/

Comment: `$('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4').find( '.class5').filter(':visible')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `is()` returns a Boolean, reflecting whether the passed-in element (or the first of the passed-in elements) matches the supplied argument.

If you switch to `filter()`, which filters the passed-in collection according to the supplied argument; if the element matches then that element is retained, otherwise it's discarded:

```js
let classFiveElems = $('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4 .class5').filter( ':visible');

console.log(classFiveElems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'>
      <div class='class2'>
        <div class='class3'>
          <div class='class4'>
            <div class='class5'>
              <p>Some text 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='class4'>
            <div class='class5'>
              <p>Some text 1</p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='class4'>
            <div class='class5' style="display:block;">
              <p>Some text 1</p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='class4'>
            <div class='class5'>
              <p>Some text 1</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What you want, though, is not just a simple check for visibility; but a test for a specific CSS property; so I'd suggest the following, which uses `filter()` but using the anonymous function:

```js
let classFiveElems = $('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4 .class5').filter(function() {
  return this.style.display === 'block';
}).addClass('found');

console.log(classFiveElems);
```

```css
.found {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' style="display:block;">
          <p>Some text 1</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5'>
          <p>Some text 1</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
if($('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4')
           .find( '.class5:first')
              .is(':visible')){
  console.log('yes');
}
```

See: https://jsbin.com/ninovic/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Actually every `div` with `class5` class has a `display: block` property.

`display: block` property is a default state of every block element (`divs` are block elements).

I've set the `display` property of other divs to `none`, just to show functionality of following code.

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('class5') && $(this).is(":visible")) {
    console.log($(this).html());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    <div class='class3'>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' style="display:none;">
          <p>Some text 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' style="display:none;">
          <p>Some text 2</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' value='t' style="display:block;">
          <p>Some text 3</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='class4'>
        <div class='class5' style="display:none;">
          <p>Some text 4</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean, you can use the [`pseudo-selector`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) inside `find()` to select the element:

```
$('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4').find('.class5:visible')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c7qx4jru/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class5').each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
   //What you want to do  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly

```
alert('is visible?', $( '.class5').is(':visible'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the .class5 having display:block property. IN Your case it will return all the elements. because all div in div contains default display property block, So it will return all of them in your case. and if you try then you have assure that only the elements(.class5) you want to select have display block property.

```
 var selector = $('.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4').find( '.class5').filter(function() {
                  return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
               });
```